# MYSQL query with if-else statement

Tags: mysql

Hi I have below table structure shown in image

[image]

I am trying to write query in mysql to fetch

name,address,mono from customer table or vendortable depend on whoseid value from transportsticker table

I tried as

```
 SELECT transportsticker.* ,AA.name,AA.address,AA.mono FROM transportsticker INNER JOIN (case when (transportsticker.whoseid='vendor') then (vendortable) else (customertable) end) AA   ON AA.id=transportsticker.vorcid AND transportsticker.id=1
```

But it is giving syntax error.
can anybody help me...?

Comment: You can't use `CASE` to decide which table to join.

Comment: what should I use..?

Comment: I would go for a better table design. Combine the `CustomerTable` and `VendorTable` and keep the type there instead.

Comment: But I want data from  CustomerTable  or VendorTable  based on whoseid column data from TransportSticker Table,
then why should I combine them

Comment: Because your table design is wrong, making you attempt bad solutions like the `CASE` statement in a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` in SQL is an *expression* and cannot be used to control flow of execution like in procedural languages.

You can use `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE` instead:

```sql
SELECT t.*, 
       COALESCE(c.name, v.name), 
       COALESCE(c.address, v.address),
       COALESCE(c.mono, v.mono) 
FROM transportsticker AS t
LEFT JOIN customertable AS c 
   ON t.whoseid='customer' AND c.id=t.vorcid
LEFT JOIN vendortable AS v
   ON t.whoseid='vendor' AND v.id=t.vorcid
WHERE t.id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT name, address, mono FROM TransportSticker, CustomerTable, VendorTable WHERE (TransportSticker.whoseid = 'vendor' AND VendorTable.id = TransportSticker.vorcid) OR (TransportSticker.whoseid = 'customer' AND CustomerTable.id = TransportSticker.vorcid)
```

This selects the corresponding entries from the Tables VendorTable and CustomerTable to your entries in TransportSticker.